# ORA-00904: : identificador inválido, Estou criando uma tabela mas aparece esse erro, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE CARRO(
   ID_CARRO VARCHAR(20),
   MODELO VARCHAR2(10),
   COR VARCHAR2(10),
   PLACA VARCHAR2(10),
   CONSTRAINT PK_CARRO PRIMARY KEY (ID_MARCA, MODELO),
   CONSTRAINT FK_CARRO_REF_MARCA FOREIGN KEY (ID_MARCA)
   REFERENCES MARCA(ID_MARCA),
);
```

Comment: mysql? esse é um erro de oracle, edite a tag correta

Answer (score 1):

Sua query tem dois erros, vou comentar aqui:

```
CREATE TABLE CARRO(
   ID_CARRO VARCHAR(20),
   MODELO VARCHAR2(10),
   COR VARCHAR2(10),
   PLACA VARCHAR2(10),
   ID_MARCA INT, <-- Falta esse campo, usado abaixo para criar a FK. Usei INT no exemplo, veja o tipo correto
   CONSTRAINT PK_CARRO PRIMARY KEY (ID_MARCA, MODELO),
   CONSTRAINT FK_CARRO_REF_MARCA FOREIGN KEY (ID_MARCA)
   REFERENCES MARCA(ID_MARCA)  <-- aqui há uma vírgula inválida, remova pois não há mais atributos a serem definidos.
);
```

- `FOREIGN KEY (ID_MARCA)` aqui está criando uma FK a partir de uma campo que não foi definido, precisa adicionar antes na lista de campos;
- `REFERENCES MARCA(ID_MARCA),` aqui há uma vírgula desnecessária, pois não há nada mais a definir na tabela, pois a seguir vem o `)`

Comment: Fiz como o seu exemplo e ainda deu erro, ORA-00904: "ID_MARCA": identificador inválido

Comment: removeu os comentários certo? veja aqui funcionando http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aad08

Comment: eu ja tenho uma tabela criada como marca, como incluo isso?

Comment: @RicardoPontual creio que a PK da tabela Carro deveria ser PRIMARY KEY (ID_CARRO, MODELO)

Comment: @RicardoPereira, no exemplo eu criei a tabela "marca" apenas para validar a *foreign key*, no seu caso não precisa. Precisa colocar o mesmo tipo da coluna "ID_MARCA" da sua tabela "marca" na coluna "ID_MARCA" dessa nova tabela, eu coloquei "INT" como exemplo, confirme pf

Comment: @Danizavtz sim concordo contigo, mas como não conheço a modelagem dele, apenas estou mostrando como resolver o problema do erro de token, ou "identificador inválido"

Comment: eu troquei e deu esse erro ORA-00905: palavra-chave não encontrada

Comment: @RicardoPontual http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aad08/3 onde errei??

Comment: compare com meu exemplo, para usar o sqlfiddle, os comandos de criação precisam estar do lado esquedor, mas ainda tem virgula a mais `FOREIGN KEY (ID_MARCA), `

Comment: consegui, obrigado pela ajuda..abraços

Comment: boa, se a pergunta ajudou, não esqueça de aceitar :)